# Change left side link of the Save As Dialog for a DropBox one?

Tags: windows-xp

I would like to add a Link to my *DropBox* folder to the frequent locations pane in the *Save As* dialog. Is there a way to modify this screen?

See the screenshot below, I have highlighted the section where I would like to have a link to the *DropBox* folder.

[image: save as dialog]

Is this possible?

Comment: Althought this is a duplicate both belong to different authors and I am not convinced to merge them due to this. I have closed the other as a duplicate of this one since this one has an answer.

Comment: @Daok: did you manage to change the dialog with TweakUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it can be done, [TweakUI](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/xp-downloads#2TC=featured) from Microsoft will be the way.

Comment: +1 and the answer. Very nice tool, didn't know we could customize the Save As Dialog with it.

Answer (score 4):

Ryan Gordon wrote a how to:
[Customize Open/Save As dialog boxes in Windows XP](http://www.insidetech.com/training/articles/3687-customize-opensave-as-dialog-boxes-in-windows-xp)

Or simply create a Reg-File with something like that:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Comdlg32]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Comdlg32\PlacesBar]
"Place1"="e:\\piotrga"
"Place2"="e:\\piotrga\\tmp"
"Place3"="e:\\piotrga\\Download"
```

As you can see, you need to escape the "\".
Hope it helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks :) This answer is great but I have to accept the other one because it was "simpler". But yours if very complete. I do not understand why someone has downvoted you.

Comment: +1 thanks this advice solved my slow File Save As problem. An old offline server was hanging around on the LHS of the Save As dialog. Your answer showed me how to identify and fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought. You can almost achieve what you want
by using the already existing third item, "My Documents",
named "Mes documents" in your example. It is directly off
the desktop and can be renamed to anything you like. For
instance I have named it "zzz" just to see the effect.

Open "My Documents" from the desktop (or in a Windows
Explorer view) and put a shortcut to the DropBox folder (and
maybe also the ***most often used folders***) in it.

Now the DropBox folder (and other folders) can quickly be
accessed from the Save As dialog. It only requires one more
click (or a <kbd>TAB</kbd>.). Double clicking (or
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) on a folder shortcut will change to that
folder in the dialog without the need to drill down to it.

Here is what it looks like on my system:

[image]

Comment: Oh, no, the Meta freehand circles have made it to SU...!